# called destructors for class during going out of scope

Tags: c++, class

Below there is a piece of code, which makes me confused:

```
class Simple 
 {
   private:
    int m_nID;
   public:
     Simple(int nID)
     {
      std::cout << "Constructing Simple " << nID<< std::endl;
      m_nID = nID;
     }
    ~Simple()
     {
     std::cout << "Destructing Simple" << m_nID << std::endl;
     } 
    int GetID() { return m_nID; }
 };
typedef struct player 
 {
   char                         id;
   char                         nick[30];
   std::vector<Simple>          mVector;
 } player, *PPER_player;

 int main()
 {
   Simple Simple1(1); // allocating on stack
   Simple Simple2(2);
   Simple Simple3(3);

   player stackplayer; 
   stackplayer.mVector.push_back(Simple1);
   stackplayer.mVector.push_back(Simple2);
   stackplayer.mVector.push_back(Simple3);
  return 0;
}
```

When i run it, this is output:

```
 Constructing Simple 1
 Constructing Simple 2
 Constructing Simple 3
 Destructing Simple1
 Destructing Simple1
 Destructing Simple2
 Destructing Simple1
 Destructing Simple2
 Destructing Simple3
 Destructing Simple3
 Destructing Simple2
 Destructing Simple1
```

Why destructors are called  so many times, when Simple1,Simple2,Simple3 go out of scope ? As you can see, destructor for Simple1 is called even 4 times, for simple3 only 2 etc.

Can you put some light on that?

Comment: Vectors need to store their elements in a contiguous region of storage. If you push more elements than the capacity of the region of storage currently allocated by the vector, the vector needs to 1) allocate a bigger one 2) move all the elements from the old storage to the new storage and push the new element there as well, and 3) delete the old storage. The third point is what causes the destructions you're observing. If you would call `reserve(6)` on the vector before doing the `push_back`s, you would see no extra destructions.

Comment: @AndyProwl now everything seems to be clear, thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These three calls of the constructor

```
Constructing Simple 1
Constructing Simple 2
Constructing Simple 3
```

correspond to statements

```
   Simple Simple1(1); // allocating on stack
   Simple Simple2(2);
   Simple Simple3(3);
```

Then when the statement

```
   stackplayer.mVector.push_back(Simple1);
```

is executed the implicitly defined copy constructor is called.

When this statement

```
   stackplayer.mVector.push_back(Simple2);
```

is executed then the vector reallocates memory. In the new extent of the memory it uses the copy constructor for copying the first element and at the same time deletes the element in the previous extent of memory.

```
 Destructing Simple1
```

When the statement

```
   stackplayer.mVector.push_back(Simple3);
```

is executed the vector again allocates a new extent of memory and copies two elements in it. So these calls of the destructor

```
 Destructing Simple1
 Destructing Simple2
```

correspond to this operation.

When after exiting the scope of main object stackplayer; is deleted. These calls of the destructor correspomd to this operation

```
 Destructing Simple1
 Destructing Simple2
 Destructing Simple3
```

And at last local objects Simple1, Simple2 and Simple3 are deleted in the reverse order relative to the order of their creating

```
 Destructing Simple3
 Destructing Simple2
 Destructing Simple1
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the vector stores a copy of each object you pass to it so there are more objects being created here than the ones *you see*.
Also, a vector is free to create as many copies of the objects its stores there is no restriction on this as per the standard. This typically, happens when a vector needs to relocate its contents.